# How to use Laravel passport if default Laravel auth is not being used

Tags: laravel, oauth, laravel-passport, laravel-migrations

I am using laravel 5.4 and not using the default Auth for user authentication with it.

I have created a custom users table and using it with a custom Auth system having all custom middlewares etc.

I have thus not run the command `php artisan make:auth` or `php aritsan migrate` in the initial setup.

How i I integrate the project with Laravel/Passport for API authentication ? Also how do I issue tokens with passport if the default auth is not used not even `Auth::attempt();`

Comment: I'm sorry, don't think I understand what you are trying to achieve. How can you have a users table without running migrations? If you created it manually, why? Can you maybe try and an example?

Comment: @Casper The table had been manually already created by a previous project and thus used in the laravel project as well.. So no such thing as a User module or Auth functionality

Comment: It sounds a bit crazy, but I guess you could some how to rewrite the personal access client token from passport, to not use the User model, I can't give you anything specific as I've never done it.